# save the input value in a 2dimentsion array

Tags: c#, winforms, arrays

how can i save the number that user enter in textbox in a 2 dimension array?

for example:

i have this numbers in textbox:45,78
and now i want to save 45,32  like this: array[0,0]=45 and array[0,1]=78

how can i do that?thanks,so much

**edited:**
oh,when i entered 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 in textbox and it takes [2,2]=56

```
 private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
  int matrixDimention = 2;
        int[,] intValues = new int[matrixDimention + 1, matrixDimention + 1];
        string[] splitValues = textBox9.Text.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < splitValues.Length; i++)
            intValues[i % (matrixDimention + 1), i % (matrixDimention + 1)] = Convert.ToInt32(splitValues[i]);
        string a=intValues[2,2].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(a);

   }
```

when i take:

```
string a=intValues[2,1].ToString();
```

it shows 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at using [String.Split Method (Char[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) and [Convert.ToInt32 Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Something like

```
string textBox = "45,78";
int[,] values = new int[1,2];
string[] textBoxSplit = textBox.Split(',');
values[0, 0] = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxSplit[0]);
values[0, 1] = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxSplit[1]);
```

**EDIT**

Example using List and Linq

```
string textBox = "45,78,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12";
List<int> list = new List<int>(textBox.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)));
```

**EDIT 2**

Longwinded example using List and foreach

```
string textBox = "45,78,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12";
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
string[] splitVals = textBox.Split(',');
foreach (string splitVal in splitVals)
    list2.Add(Convert.ToInt32(splitVal));
```

**EDIT**

*Enter the matrix*

```
string textBox = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
int matrixDimention = 2;
int[,] intValues = new int[matrixDimention + 1, matrixDimention + 1];
string[] splitValues = textBox.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < splitValues.Length; i++)
    intValues[i/(matrixDimention + 1), i%(matrixDimention + 1)] = Convert.ToInt32(splitValues[i]);
```

**EDIT**

*Follow the white rabbit*

```
string textBox = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
int matrixDimention = 2;
int[,] intValues = new int[matrixDimention + 1, matrixDimention + 1];
string[] splitValues = textBox.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < splitValues.Length; i++)
    intValues[i/(matrixDimention + 1), i%(matrixDimention + 1)] = Convert.ToInt32(splitValues[i]);
string displayString = "";
for (int inner = 0; inner < intValues.GetLength(0); inner ++)
{
    for (int outer = 0; outer < intValues.GetLength(1); outer++)
        displayString += String.Format("{0}\t", intValues[inner, outer]);
    displayString += Environment.NewLine;
}
MessageBox.Show(displayString);
```

Comment: thanks,how can i make this with a for loop?for example when i dont know how many numbers user enter

Comment: What exactly are your intensions, and why specifically an array?

Comment: i mean in textbox user enter for example 50 numbers,then what should i do to save that in 2d array?

Comment: Why are you forcing this into an array, Why not a List<int>?

Comment: because i dont know how to use list<int> and dont have enough time to learn it sir

Comment: thanks,but now i cant save numbers in 2d array,for example i cant do this:splitvals[0,0]=15

Comment: Why, o why do you need to save it in a 2d array?

Comment: because i want to save like matrix

Comment: OK< matrix it is then. Why 2D? will there be multiple inputs to split, say "1,2,3,4" and "5,6,7,8" and "9,10,11,12" all into a 2D?

Comment: i didnt understand clear what you said,for example i want to save matix[0,0]=12 and matrix[0,1]=13,etc according to my inputs,i mean i want to put first input in matrix[0,0] and second in matrix[0,1] and etc

Comment: YEs, that is fine, but what will be at matrix[1,0]?

Comment: the user says the lengh and width of matrix for example when the lengh and width of marix is 2,place [0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2] fill with the numbers that user enter in textbox for example in :1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ,matrix[1,0]=4

Comment: Is this your first time with C#? Or programming for that matter? You have to try too, We cannot spoon you, or you will not learn *ANYTHING*

Comment: giving code like this seems a bit stupid. Not willing to learn or why it doesn't work seems to me a lost cause

Answer (score 1):

try this assuming array is a string array

```
str[] input = textBox.Text.Split(',');

 if(input.Length > 1)
  {
     arr[0,0] = input[0];

     arr[0,1]= input[1];

   }
```